# How to add multiple quotations in HTML?

Tags: html

```html
<div class="background_image" style="background-image:url('{% static images/home_slider.jpg %}')"></div>
```

In the above line, I want to add quotation before and after `images/home_slider.jpg`. As you can see, I have used single and double quotes once, how do I add another single or double quote?

Comment: That's not plain HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML entities inside the first pair of quotation marks. Single quotation mark is 
`&apos;` and double is `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that what you posted is not plain HTML: You can use strings with `&quot;`

```css
#bg {
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: url(&quot;https://via.placeholder.com/500&quot;)"  id="bg"> 

</div>
```